# How to Grant User to access all the views in SQL Server but not table and stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to create a new temp user who will have only access to all views to read only.

User should not have to read access to table and stored procedures.

I tried below query but it is giving access to table as well.

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember db_datareader, 'user1'

GRANT VIEW DATABASE STATE TO  'user1'
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO 'user1'
```

Comment: My Requirement is to create an User With Low privilege i.e. only access to read any view in the DataBase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary way to do this is to grant permissions to only the view objects. You can loop through all of the views in the db with the following:

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT GrantStatement = 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + TABLE_NAME + ' TO user1'
INTO #grants
FROM
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Views

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #grants)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @sql = GrantStatement
    FROM #grants

    EXEC (@sql)

    DELETE #grants
    WHERE GrantStatement = @sql
END
```

A second technique would be to create a separate schema used only for views, then grant permission to the entire schema. That could be done like this:

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::ViewSchema TO user1
```

Comment: Is there any single command which takes care of all the view. instead of going to all views one by one?
As i am using Datawareshouse i have have thousands of view

Comment: Kind of. See the second technique I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **DENY** function to prevent the user from having access to the table and the stored procedure. For example:

```
DENY SELECT on tablename to user1;
```

As you have added user1 to the db_datareader database role, they will be able to perform **SELECT** statements on objects within the database unless you **DENY** them access to the objects.

Comment: I am looking for generic statement for all the view. not single object.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. open SQL server Managment Studio
Step 2. use [schmeaName]  -- existing schema to create new schema and new login user
Step 3. -- Create a database loginuser for the login .

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = N'UserLoginName')
BEGIN
CREATE USER [UserLoginName] FOR LOGIN [UserLoginName]
END;
GO

CREATE LOGIN UserLoginName
WITH PASSWORD = '123@saa';
GO

Step 4.

/********  Create separate Schema for UserLoginName  to access Views:    ********/

IF NOT EXISTS (
SELECT  schema_name
FROM    information_schema.schemata
WHERE   schema_name = 'SCHEMA_VIEWS' )

BEGIN
EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE SCHEMA SCHEMA_VIEWS'
END
GO

Step 5. Create View  -- use existing table inside this view

CREATE view [SCHEMA_VIEWS].MyView
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Tbl_student

GO

step 6.
/***   Provide select grant to created View for given user***/

GRANT SELECT ON [SCHEMA_VIEWS].MyView TO UserLoginName