New SQL Server Role Access to all views for discovery
I know how to grant a user access to all views currently created within a database, but how would I create a database role that would include all views created in the future?
I know we have db_datareader, but I want to limit it to just views.
Right now I am not worried about schema based access (but we are heading that way).
I found this helpful to loop through all of the views in the db
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47664575/3481766 - digital.aaron
but as I said above has anyone found a way to assign this to a DB_Role?

Not sure it's possible, unless you do some kind of DDL trigger that adds permissions automatically. Sounds like a bad idea anyway, do you want to grant people everything without thought?

You could ensure you CREATE those VIEWs on a specific schema, and then GRANT the permission to SELECT on that schema instead. Just make sure you don't CREATE your TABLEs on that schema too.

There is no way to grant permissions to all future views.  You can grant permissions to all future objects at the database level, or the schema level.
If you really needed to you could use a DDL trigger, or a SQL Agent job to do the GRANTs.
